# How to remove all event handlers in Windows App?

Tags: c#, windows-store

Here is the situation:

```
    public async void Test()
    {
        List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        var folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
        var queryResults = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
        //queryResults.ContentsChanged += null;
        queryResults.ContentsChanged += QueryResults_ContentsChanged;
    }
```

I call Test many times, so when some changes happened in that folder, QueryResults_ContentsChanged fires for manytimes, but I just want only once.  I tried "+= null", but it does not work, so I have no idea how to remove all event handlers from the local variable queryResults.

Comment: `queryResults.ContentsChanged -= QueryResults_ContentsChanged;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any use case that requires calling your `Test` method many times, I suggest verify/validate your design.

What I understood from your question is, you want to check whether  `QueryResults_ContentsChanged` is attached to any other `event` or not, it is not *possible* (unless you've your own logic).

In general, an event can be unsubscribed as below.

```
queryResults.ContentsChanged -= QueryResults_ContentsChanged;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-=` operator to Unsubscribe event.

```
queryResults.ContentsChanged -= QueryResults_ContentsChanged;
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) for more detail that how to `Subscribe` and `Unsubscribe` events